# Is there a benefit to Softmax when calculus isn't being used?

Tags: calculus, probability

Softmax is commonly used in artificial intelligence to compute the probability of each item in a set and choose the most probable item.

$$\sigma(Z)=\frac{(e^{z_i})}{\sum^K_{j=1} e^{z_j}}$$

This is beneficial because it can be derived to obtain a gradient, which would then be used to modify a neural network's weights.

However, if the problem statement is to simply find the most probable item in the set and calculus isn't being used, does Softmax provide any additional benefit as opposed to simply choosing the max-valued item of the set?

Comment: If the set is big enough, it might not be so easy to just pick the biggest element. However, it is relatively easy to sample from the softmax distribution using something like MCMC or simulated annealing. These samples can then be used to estimate the max-valued item.